# disable descending sort in tablesorter

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I've got tablesorter working to my liking with one exception: for one of my columns I would like to disable the ability to do a descending sort. So when someone clicks on this column, the order will always be the same, i.e. in ascending order.

Is there an option for this with tablesorter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the original tablesorter has code for `lockedOrder`, it can only be used to lock in a descending sort ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/eY8uH/1470/) & [ref](https://github.com/christianbach/tablesorter/blob/master/jquery.tablesorter.js#L510))

```
$('table').tablesorter({
    headers : {
        0: { lockedOrder: 1 }
    }
});
```

I have a [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) which has fixed this issue so that the `lockedOrder` can be set as either ascending or descending ([demo](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-options-headers-locked.html)).

Comment: Works like a charm. I'm sorting based on an attribute so I just reversed it's order and stuck with the original tablesorter, but I'll keep yours bookmarked for when I need to sort by text.